# Hot key to set window size in macOS

Tags: macos, hotkeys

OS: macOS Monterey 12.2.1

Is it possible to create a hot key so that it would be possible to set the size of the active window (web browser, application, etc.) in predefined pixels?
For example, I have an active Google Chrome window, I press the hot key and its size becomes 1280x720.

Comment: Have you tried something, does it work?

Comment: @Toto for now im using Rectangle app, but it can't set custom window size, only predefined in program.

Comment: You can take a look at hammerspoon, thought it's a litter complicated. And this questions is too open to answer, so it should be paste on other sites like reddit.